# Удалить список "Недавние" в программах Office, Windows 10

Tags: office

В Office 2016, если во время работы над файлом нажать ПКМ по Word, Excel и т.д. в панели задач, то высвечивается список "Недавние", т.е. список последних открытых файлов.

Не могу понять, как чистить этот список или вообще заблокировать офису возможность хранения этих данных.

В Файл > Параметры > Дополнительно > Экран > "Число документов в списке последних файлов" установлено значение 0. Эта опция не помогает.

Comment: HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search\RecentApps\%Application CLSID%\RecentItems - почистить и перестартовать сеанс.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Почищу и поставлю системе запрет на редактирование.

Comment: *поставлю системе запрет на редактирование* Рискуешь поломать нормальную работу приложения. К тому же текущие значения в сеансе кэшируются независимо от реестра.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда буду разбираться, как сделать очистку автоматической.

Comment: *буду разбираться, как сделать очистку автоматической* Что тут разбираться-то? VBS-скрипт или батник - и в шедулер на вход/выход учётки его.

Comment: Ну, я новичок и тут все не совсем просто, пользователям политиками заблокирован доступ к редактированию реестра, ветка реестра "HKCU" это ветка конкретного пользователя же, верно? Если я засуну в шедулер от имени пользователя, то ничего не отработает, а если я засуну от имени админа, то будет чиститься ветка админа, а не та, что нужна. Получается, что я должен сделать скрипт или батник, который будет подключать ветку конкретного пользователя и чистить ее из под админа (или всех пользователей)

Comment: *ветка реестра "HKCU" это ветка конкретного пользователя же, верно?* Да. *пользователям политиками заблокирован доступ к редактированию реестра* Ерунда. Заблокирован только запуск Regedit.EXE. Однако Reg.Exe, а тем более средства, не использующие внешних утилит (скажем, та же правка реестра через VBS) вполне себе доступны.

Comment: @Akina, напишите, пожалуйста, ответ.